# derivative over nested integrals

Tags: calculus, derivatives, integral-equations

I have the following problem. First an example for two-variable functions

Let $A=A(t,\tau)$ and $B=B(t,\tau)$

If I want to compute the following

$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau A(t,\tau) B(t,\tau)$ one can apply the following rule

\begin{equation}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau A(t,\tau) B(t,\tau) =  \int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau \Big( \frac{\partial}{\partial t} A \Big) B + \int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau A \Big( \frac{\partial}{\partial t} B \Big) + \Big( A(t,\tau) B(t,\tau)\Big)\rvert_{\tau=t} \end{equation}

Now the problem: the functions depend on four time arguments, that is

$A=A(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2)$ and $B=B(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2)$

and I want to compute

\begin{equation}  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau \int_\tau^t \mathrm{d}\tau_1 \int_\tau^{\tau_1} \mathrm{d}\tau_2~ A(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2) B(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2)     \end{equation}

What would be the rule for this case?

I would really appreciate your help!!!

Stefan

Comment: You have named $t$ the integral limit but also the variable inside the integral. It's impossible to understand what you are actually computing.

Comment: Hi, yes this is the point. It's the same t in the integral limit as the one with respect to which you are taking the derivative. See the case for two variables.

Comment: You did not understand my remark. When you write $\int_0^tf(t,\,\tau)\mathrm dt$, did you mean $\int_0^tf(t,\,\tau)\mathrm d\tau$ or $\int_0^tf(t',\,\tau)\mathrm dt'$ ? Please edit your question !

Comment: Sorry!!! My mistake, I was sloppy :-(. So now the question is posed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau F(t,\tau,\tau_1)$$

with

$$
F(t,\tau,\tau_1)=\int_\tau^t \mathrm{d}\tau_1 \int_\tau^{\tau_1} \mathrm{d}\tau_2~ A(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2) B(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2)
$$

and apply the same principles that you applied in the other case.

Comment: \begin{equation}  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau \int_\tau^t \mathrm{d}\tau_1 \int_\tau^{\tau_1} \mathrm{d}\tau_2~ A(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2) B(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2)  =   \end{equation}

$$  \int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau \int_\tau^t \mathrm{d}\tau_1 \int_\tau^{\tau_1} \mathrm{d}\tau_2 \Big(\big(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} A\big)B + A\big(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} B\big)\Big) + \int_\tau^t \mathrm{d}\tau_1 \int_\tau^{\tau_1} \mathrm{d}\tau_2~ \big(A.B\big)|_{\tau = t}~ +  \int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau~ \big(A.B \big)|_{\tau_2 = \tau_1, \tau_1 = t}$$

Could you verify this?

Comment: @Hasan: That can't be right; the dimensions are wrong -- you differentiated once with respect to time but the last term is missing two time integrations instead of one, so it has units of time missing.

Comment: Stefan and I are using this rule for some of our work, and the last term in this way leads to the explanation of why some terms are present in the solution of what we're looking at. (We're trying to understand the correct way to do this differentiation from its implementation in an example, but it's very hard to see due to the length of expressions involved). Could you please write the correct expression? (is it just the same with just an additional $\int_{\tau}^{t} d\tau_1$ in the last term?)

Comment: Hi everyone and thanks for the suggestions. So, following joriki's comment this is what I got                                                            \begin{equation}\int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau  \Bigg( \int_\tau^{t} \mathrm{d}\tau_2 ~ A(t,\tau,t,\tau_2)B(t,\tau,t,\tau_2) \Bigg)  \\
&+  \int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau \int_\tau^t \mathrm{d}\tau_1  \int_\tau^{\tau_1}\mathrm{d}\tau_2~\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Bigg( A(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2)\Bigg) B(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2) +  A(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2)  \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Bigg( B(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2) \Bigg)~.\end{equation}

Comment: @stefan: The ampersand is what's causing it not to be displayed properly.

Comment: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau \int_\tau^t \mathrm{d}\tau_1 \int_\tau^{\tau_1}\mathrm{d}\tau_2 A(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2) B(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2)  = \int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau  \Bigg( \int_\tau^{t} \mathrm{d}\tau_2 ~ A(t,\tau,t,\tau_2)B(t,\tau,t,\tau_2) \Bigg)  +  \int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau \int_\tau^t \mathrm{d}\tau_1  \int_\tau^{\tau_1}\mathrm{d}\tau_2~\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Bigg( A(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2)\Bigg) B(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2) +  A(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2)  \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Bigg( B(t,\tau,\tau_1,\tau_2) \Bigg)~.$$

Comment: @stefan: Yes, this is correct (though I'd put parentheses around the sum in the last integral to clarify that the second term is also being integrated). Usually there would be one more term, in which $t$ is substituted for $\tau$, but it's zero because it's an integral over $\tau_1$ from $t$ to $t$.

Answer (score -1):

As a general principle to avoid mistakes, I would recommend to compute
$$ F(t+\delta t)-F(t)$$
and expand it to the first order in $\delta t$.

In your case, for $F(t)=\int_0^t f(t,\tau)\mathrm d\tau$ this gives
$$F(t+\delta t)-F(t)=\int_0^t \left[f(t+\delta t,\tau)-f(t,\tau)\right]\mathrm d\tau+\int_t^{t+\delta t}f(t+\delta t,\tau)\mathrm d\tau.$$
From this you deduce immediately that $F'(t)=\int_0^t\partial_tf(t,\tau)\mathrm d\tau+f(t,t)$.

Comment: Could the person who downvoted this answer leave a comment explaining why ?